# Eslint glob does not work without extensions

Tags: javascript, node.js, glob, eslint

I am running my Eslint through npm like so:

```
"eslint": "eslint resources/assets/js/**/*"
```

This does not work though, I have to manually specify an extension.

```
"eslint": "eslint resources/assets/js/**/*.js"
```

In that case it does work. I have `.vue` and `.js` files though so that is a bit of a problem.

I would love to be able to do something like this:

```
"eslint": "eslint resources/assets/js/**/*.{js, vue}"
```

But I don't think something like that exists yet for ESlint.

If this behavior normal and what could I do to still check my .vue and .js files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the space between the `js` and `vue` file extensions:

```
"eslint": "eslint resources/assets/js/**/*.{js,vue}"
```

Alternatively, I am pretty sure you could also use:

```
"eslint": "eslint resources/assets/js/**/*.(js|vue)"
```